# Are VHDL character substitutions ever used in real life?

Tags: vhdl

VHDL allows the following substitutions, presumably because some computers might not support the vertical bar (or pipe symbol) (|) or the hash (or pound sign / number sign) (#):

`case A|B` can be written as `case A!B`

`16#fff#` can be written as `16:fff:`

Any computer nowadays supports the vertical bar and the hash symbol, so I figured nobody uses these substitutions... Until somebody requested support for the exclamation mark.

My question: is this a lone case or are other people also using the exclamation mark as substitute for the vertical bar? Anybody using the colon?

Comment: Just one answer, from @Martin. I will assume that (almost) nobody uses character substitutions in VHDL. Marking this question as answered.

Comment: C has those things too, from when terminals and punch cards had very few characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data point 1: Not me :)

And I've never seen it as far as I recall in any code - nor was I taught it at any point (in fact, this is the first I knew of those substitutions).

I had a quick look in Ashenden's *Designer's Guide to VHDL*, and the `!` alternative is not even mentioned when the `|` is introduced for `case` statements.

Comment: The substitutions are more of a footnote for the lexer. I remember when I migrated from a Commodore-64 home computer to a PC, I was surprised to discover the existence of the bar symbol. Today, I'm sure every computer supports these characters.

Answer (score 1):

These are inherited from Ada (in which they are obsolescent since Ada95).  The Ada83 Rationale says "For portability reasons, it is possible to write any program in a 56 character subset of the ISO character set." in which ISO character set must be understood as ISO-646, aka ASCII (well ISO-646 has provision for replacing some characters for national variant, ASCII can be understood as the US national variant of ISO-646)

There is a third replacement: % can be use instead of " as string delimitor (both must be replaced).

I seem to remember that EBCDIC is using | or ! for the same code point depending on the variant.